# Spring boot + Spring Security + Google OAuth2: How to get access token and call some Google API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, google-api, google-oauth

According to google documentation, there are [following steps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#obtainingaccesstokens) for calling some google API using OAuth2.

1. Prerequisites (includes configuration in developer console)
2. Obtaining access token
3. Calling the API using HTTP call, while adding access token in the header

---

I have (IMHO) set up the prerequisites properly. I am authenticating the user through Spring Boot + Spring Security, as mentioned in [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-with-google-sign-in-in-spring-boot). I have got this step right as I can get users authenticated.

Now, if I return the user details that are stored in `principle` user as JSON as follows

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }
```

I see an output similar to this,

```
{
    "authorities": [
        {
            "authority": "ROLE_USER"
        }
    ],
    "details": {
        "remoteAddress": "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
        "sessionId": "CB3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "tokenValue": "ya29.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "tokenType": "Bearer",
        "decodedDetails": null
    },
    "authenticated": true,
    "userAuthentication": {
        "authorities": [
            {
                "authority": "ROLE_USER"
            }
        ],
        "details": {
            "id": "10xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "given_name": "John",
            "family_name": "Doe",
            "link": "https://plus.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "picture": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/photo.jpg",
            "locale": "en"
        },
        "authenticated": true,
        "principal": "106xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "credentials": "N/A",
        "name": "106xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "principal": "106xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "clientOnly": false,
    "credentials": "",
    "oauth2Request": {
        "clientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "scope": [],
        "requestParameters": {},
        "resourceIds": [],
        "authorities": [],
        "approved": true,
        "refresh": false,
        "redirectUri": null,
        "responseTypes": [],
        "extensions": {},
        "refreshTokenRequest": null,
        "grantType": null
    },
    "name": "106xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

The access token seems to be present in the above details.

---

What I am wondering about is,

1. What about sending required scopes through the authorisation request? I must have to do it somewhere as when I tried to make a call to Google+ API(which has been enabled) using CURL, I did not get user email address as expected.
2. How do I do all this through spring boot + spring security? Am I supposed to use some inbuilt methods, use [google API client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/) or something else?

Comment: Scopes are sent when requesting authencation of the user.  The google+ api will only return email if the user has set email to public this includes the currently authencated user.

Comment: @DaImTo How do I add the scope to the request. As spring boot is handling it behind the scenes, do I need to override/call some method?

Comment: @DaImTo I figured that out. All I had to do is add "email" to application.yml file. Now I won't have to make API calls, as all the details I need have already been fetched by Spring. But how do I access those details from the principle object?